# pyinstaller command creates exe but does not work fine

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, exe, pyinstaller

I tried many combinations like installing PyQt5 just because of below missing modules like PyQt4.QtCore, subprocess, pickle etc.

Also I tried to path to datas and import hidden lines but still I would get the _tkinter error as warning. I am not sure if I am missing anything. I checked many many stackoverflow questions and tried many advises. Probably I am missing something. A direction to help would be great. Thanks in advance!

Pyinstaller command to create .exe

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --log-level=WARN --log-level=DEBUG --onedir --noconsole --noupx -i icon=parser.ico incparser21jun.spec incparser21jun.py
```

Spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['incparser21jun.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Redist\\10.0.18362.0\\ucrt\\DLLs\\x86', 
                     'C:\\Users\\userid\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\Scripts',
                     'C:\\Users\\userid\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\libs',
                     'C:\\Users\\userid\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\Lib'
                    ],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[
                 ('C:\\Users\\userid\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\ttkthemes','ttkthemes'),
                 ('C:\\Users\\userid\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\Lib\\tkinter','tkinter')
             ],
             hiddenimports=['tkinter', 'ttkthemes'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=['olefile', 'posix'],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='incparser21jun',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=False,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False , icon='parser.ico')
```

Includes in the incparser21jun.py

```
import os, sys, re, binascii                         # IMPORT LOGGING
import string
import logging
import textwrap
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox                 
from ttkthemes import themed_tk as tk          # lets style the window
from ttkthemes import ThemedTk
```

Warning message in Build folder:

```
This file lists modules PyInstaller was not able to find. This does not
necessarily mean this module is required for running you program. Python and
Python 3rd-party packages include a lot of conditional or optional module. For
example the module 'ntpath' only exists on Windows, whereas the module
'posixpath' only exists on Posix systems.

Types if import:
* top-level: imported at the top-level - look at these first
* conditional: imported within an if-statement
* delayed: imported from within a function
* optional: imported within a try-except-statement

IMPORTANT: Do NOT post this list to the issue-tracker. Use it as a basis for
           yourself tracking down the missing module. Thanks!

missing module named _posixsubprocess - imported by subprocess (conditional), C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\incparser21jun.py (top-level)
missing module named org - imported by pickle (optional), C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\incparser21jun.py (top-level)
missing module named readline - imported by cmd (delayed, conditional, optional), code (delayed, conditional, optional), pdb (delayed, optional), C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\incparser21jun.py (top-level)
missing module named _winreg - imported by platform (delayed, optional), C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\incparser21jun.py (top-level)
missing module named _scproxy - imported by urllib.request (conditional)
missing module named java - imported by platform (delayed), C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\incparser21jun.py (top-level)
missing module named 'java.lang' - imported by platform (delayed, optional), C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\incparser21jun.py (top-level), xml.sax._exceptions (conditional)
missing module named vms_lib - imported by platform (delayed, conditional, optional), C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\incparser21jun.py (top-level)
missing module named termios - imported by tty (top-level), C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\incparser21jun.py (top-level), getpass (optional)
excluded module named _frozen_importlib - imported by importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\incparser21jun.py (top-level)
missing module named _frozen_importlib_external - imported by importlib._bootstrap (delayed), importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\incparser21jun.py (top-level)
missing module named UserDict - imported by PIL.PdfParser (optional)
missing module named __builtin__ - imported by PIL.Image (optional), C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\incparser21jun.py (top-level)
missing module named cffi - imported by PIL.Image (optional), PIL.PyAccess (top-level), C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\incparser21jun.py (top-level), PIL.ImageTk (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named grp - imported by shutil (optional), tarfile (optional), pathlib (delayed), C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\incparser21jun.py (top-level)
missing module named pathlib2 - imported by PIL.Image (optional), C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\incparser21jun.py (top-level)
missing module named 'org.python' - imported by copy (optional), C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\incparser21jun.py (top-level), xml.sax (delayed, conditional)
missing module named PySide2 - imported by PIL.ImageQt (conditional, optional), C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\incparser21jun.py (top-level)
missing module named 'PySide2.QtCore' - imported by PIL.ImageQt (conditional, optional), C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\incparser21jun.py (top-level)
missing module named PyQt4 - imported by C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\incparser21jun.py (top-level)
missing module named 'PyQt4.QtCore' - imported by PIL.ImageQt (conditional, optional), C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\incparser21jun.py (top-level)
missing module named PySide - imported by C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\incparser21jun.py (top-level)
missing module named 'PySide.QtCore' - imported by PIL.ImageQt (conditional, optional), C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\incparser21jun.py (top-level)
excluded module named olefile - imported by PIL.FpxImagePlugin (top-level), PIL.MicImagePlugin (top-level)
missing module named numpy - imported by PIL.ImageFilter (optional), C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\incparser21jun.py (top-level)
missing module named tkimg - imported by ttkthemes._widget (delayed, conditional, optional), C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\incparser21jun.py (top-level)
excluded module named posix - imported by os (conditional, optional), C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\incparser21jun.py (top-level)
missing module named pwd - imported by posixpath (delayed, conditional), shutil (optional), tarfile (optional), http.server (delayed, optional), webbrowser (delayed), pathlib (delayed, conditional, optional), C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\incparser21jun.py (top-level), netrc (delayed, conditional), getpass (delayed)
missing module named _dummy_threading - imported by dummy_threading (optional), C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\incparser21jun.py (top-level)
missing module named Tkinter - imported by ttkthemes._tkinter (conditional), C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\incparser21jun.py (top-level), PIL.ImageTk (conditional)
missing module named ttk - imported by ttkthemes._tkinter (conditional), C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\incparser21jun.py (top-level)
```

Comment: What does "not work fine" mean? Does it crash? Generate errors? Display incorrect windows? Also, why are you including PyQT4 modules if you're using Tkinter?

Comment: When I click on .exe file it gives error message - "Failed to execute script incparser21jun" I did not include PyQT4 module...looks like it is imported internally by another. I am not sure I am getting missing module for java.lang,PySide2, PyQt4.QtCore, etc..Since I am getting the error ""Failed to execute script incparser21jun" I am trying to debug the warning message which is stored in build folder. Is there something else I need to look at?

Comment: Also, these 2 warnings are present inspite of adding ttkthemes to spec file missing module named Tkinter - imported by ttkthemes._tkinter (conditional), C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\incparser21jun.py (top-level), PIL.ImageTk (conditional)
missing module named ttk - imported by ttkthemes._tkinter (conditional), C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\incparser21jun.py (top-level)

Comment: You shouldn't pass both the spec file and py file to pyinstaller. When passing a spec file, all other arguments would be ignored.

Comment: I did remove all the other command but the resulting warning and error is same. Command used: pyinstaller --noconfirm --log-level=WARN --log-level=DEBUG incparser21jun.spec incparser21jun.py